# setSelectionRange for input type="time"

Tags: javascript, html, selection-api

I have a dialog box that has an HTML5 input field with a `type="time"` in it.

When the dialog appears, I want to default the editing to the "minutes" portion of the dialog. I can't see a way to do it.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YT83w/2/) example that tries to use:

```
$("#t")[0].setSelectionRange(3, 5);
```

to no avail.

Is there a way to do this?

---

NOTE: the w3c spec [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#time-state-%28type=time%29) specifically has this quote:

> The following IDL attributes and methods do not apply to the element:
>   checked, files, selectionStart, selectionEnd, and selectionDirection
>   IDL attributes; select(), setRangeText(), and setSelectionRange()
>   methods.

Which might mean this simply isn't possible.

---

NOTE 2: Chrome throws this error when attempting to call this method. Other browsers may throw different errors:

> Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that
>   is not, or is no longer, usable.

Comment: I believe your current code will give an exception of `"Object [object Object] has no method 'setSelectionRange'"`, this is because the JQuery object doesn't have that method. You need to call it on a DOM element, you can do this with `$("#t")[0]` or plain javascript `getElementById`... however, it seems that will then throw a new error: `"An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable."`, and I am not sure how to fix that one. Note, if you use a normal `Text` input type then it would work ok, so seems specific to `Time` input type

Comment: Hey thanks. Fixed my code. That was just a typo when typing up the example. I was really concerned about the "An attempt was made..." issue. Added more notes to that affect in the description.

Comment: "Which might mean this simply isn't possible." I think that's the answer unfortunately :(

Comment: I have the same question, but for a date input.

Answer (score 0):

Just set it using some js.

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].value = "13:24"
```

```html
<input type="time" id="appt" name="appt" min="09:00" max="18:00" required>
```